# Change the text size of a plot

Tags: r, plot

In the simple plot:

```
  plot()
```

How can anyone change with easy way the text size of x, y labels and axis and the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cex.lab` to control for the size of lables, `cex.axis` for axes and `cex.main` for title size.

From `?par` you can read:

```
cex.lab 
The magnification to be used for x and y labels relative to the current
setting of cex.
```

Take a look at `?par` for learning about `cex.*` options